# Update Hudson build result status after external tests

Tags: testing, hudson, build-automation, staging

We use Hudson for our build/CI needs. In addition to unit tests (running during build) I have a staging environment that runs additional integration tests. Basically the build happens and then build artifacts are submitted the external system. I do not wish to block a Hudson build to wait for integration tests (as that locks the station into idle, and prevents it from building anything else). What I want is to update the the result of the build with the result of the external tests (and attach some logs back to the build, if possible).

Now because the staging environment is asynchronous to the build system (i.e. other systems/people can submit tests), Hudson can't be just monitoring what goes on there right after the build. Hudson build just goes into a test queue. So, I need to notify Hudson, it can't be polling something for updates.

Does Hudson support such behaviour, and if so, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the hudson users mailing list [1]

[1] http://java.net/projects/hudson/lists/users/archive

Comment: I don't see a post button, so I'm afraid I'm too young to know how those work.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the asynchronous wait issue, you can use the build triggering with an authentication token, and use it in a script.

The **Build Triggers** section has a **Trigger Builds Remotely (e.g. from scripts)**, which when selected allows you to enter an **Authentication Token (which has the descriptive text from your question)**.

You can thus, remotely trigger the build from a script, i.e., have it as part of the integration test script and trigger the build job using this authentication token.

..

You can have a downstream project just for result collection that integrates the results from various tests and report it to the master and aggregate them all. This project can be triggered using the authentication token, or if there is a single integration test job, you can tie it up as a downstream project.